# php-sql delete value if exists in one of my two tables

Tags: php, sql, database

I have created a chat system where students and academic staff can communicate between them. I have developed a form were I can get the name of the club were the conversation exists, and the value of the `staff_id` for another reason.

The problem is that I can not delete the records from 3 tables. I know that first I have to check if a specific id exists in `staff_table` or `stu_table` but I cannot figure out the query that I have to use.

The first table is the `staff_message` (columns: `staff_id, m_id`), the second is the `stu_message` (columns: `stu_id, mid`) and the third is the `message` table (columns: `id, text, date, type`).

Here you can see my code:

```
    <?php
        include_once('connect.php');

        $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['clubname']);
        $staff_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['staff_id']);

        if(empty($name)) {
            header("Location: ../options.php?index==empty");
            exit(); 
        }
        else {
            $quer = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM message WHERE type='$name'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quer)) {   
                $message_id = $row['id'];
            }

            $query4 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM staff_message WHERE m_id='$message_id'");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query4) >= 1)
            {
                $query5 = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM staff_message WHERE m_id='$message_id'");
            } else {
                    echo "not here staff"; //see if finds the value   
            }

            $query8 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stu_message WHERE mid='$message_id'");   

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query8) >= 1)
            {
                 $query5 = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM stu_message WHERE mid='$message_id'");
            } else {
                    echo "not here stu";//see if finds the value   
            }


    $query= mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM message WHERE type = '$name'");  

    header("Location: ../options.php?delete==success");

        }
        ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** I tested each code separately and I saw that they both work. What I mean is that when there is only one row of student message then the message is deleted as well as the row in reference table (`stu_message`). That also applies for the academic staff table.

Answer (score 0):

May Be
You Have 3 Tables
1.Staff_Message
2.Stu_Message
3.Message

can you tell me which is the main id and which id refrence in tables then i can make query according your requirement

Comment: First of all thank you @Dilip Shekhawat about your answer. Here is a picture of my tables: https://imgur.com/9GwhZsr If there is any problem inform me

Answer (score 0):

According To Your Image Your Base Table Is Message Then Mid Refer In Two Table(stu_message and staff_message)--- Right?

Comment: yes the main table is the message and the mid ref the other two tables

Comment: Ok i Think You Can Change Serial Of Record Delete 1.You Can Find Id From Name Based And Store Your ID In Variable Then You Delete Record In Message Table Then You Can Delete Record From Both Table According Assign Variable Id

Comment: I can't delete the record from message table. I have to delete the record from the ref. table first (staff_message, stu_message)

Comment: $quer = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM message WHERE type='$name'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quer)){  
                $message_id = $row['id'];
            } When You Putting This Code Then You Get Correct Id

Comment: I get the correct id for every record that the type equals with the name of the club

Comment: ok so please tell me one by one........................ $querry4=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM staff_message WHERE m_id='$message_id'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($querry4)>=1)
               {
                $querry5=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM staff_message WHERE m_id='$message_id'");
               }else{
                    echo "not here staff"; //see if finds the value   
               } this code run correctly

Comment: When there is only one message from the staff then the code works but when I have two messages, one from the staff and one from the student then it doesn't work. The whole code deletes only the message from the student. The opposite happens also when the first message is from the student and the second from the accademic staff

Comment: Ok So Both Query Put In While Loop Because Both Query Out Of While Loop

Comment: I think that I can find a querry that it will check the ref table and if the value exists then it will delete the message from the message table